# Does a light bulb socket security camera require the wall switch to be on?

Tags: light, security, ip-camera

Does the light switch have to stay on all time for the camera to work?

Where I want to place it there are 20 accent lights hooked up to 1 light switch. Are there any workarounds if I don't want to keep all 20 lights on 24/7?

Comment: The answer to the first question seems so obvious that I can't help wonder if I'm misinterpreting it. If your cameral has a rechargeable battery in it you should mention that to us. If not, how can it possibly function without power?

Comment: Please give us a drawing of some sort (doesn't have to be professional, to scale, or anything like that) because a picture is worth 1000 words, and it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. I cannot fathom how you'll be able to do this without rewiring the fixture that you want to put the camera in, and if you're going to be doing more wiring, it seems reasonable (to me, at least) to widen your search to other camera types that don't rely on picking up power from a light socket. For example, Power over Ethernet cameras are very reliable and don't count on WiFi.

Answer (score 2):

> Does a light bulb socket security camera require the wall switch to be on?

if the light bulb socket is on a wall switch, then **yup**

> Are there any workarounds.

maybe, depends on what you have to work with and what compromises are acceptable... go manually unplug all 20 lights.

Answer (score 0):

A screw in light bulb security camera receives its operating power from the light socket. The light socket receives its power ONLY when the switch is in the on position.

In order to allow the camera to maintain power full time, you will have to implement a break point, aka switch, between the power source of the camera and the power source of the accent lights.

I can envision a possible solution but it requires that you have other resources. The screw-in camera must screw into a Y-adapter, both sides will be energized. The non-camera side of the Y-adapter would then provide power to the accent lights, also on a full time basis, but...

That leg of the Y-adapter should then receive a remote switchable outlet into which the accent lights would connect. Leave the camera powered full time, use the remote switchable outlet to regulate the accent lights as desired.

[image: BN_link power control]

The above product is from Amazon ([photo source](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07CX5KLXN)) and is something I use on a daily basis, for various applications. It does require local home network connectivity, but not necessarily internet access.

As requested, more information. Dual light bulb socket adapter used as search terms generates a number of candidates, this one from [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07GZ9F4XG) is typical and others are more ornate.

[image: dual light bulb socket adapter]

In the process of clarifying, I discovered what may be a more suitable adapter, also from [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09R1H8FHN):

[image: light bulb power adapter]

As one can see in the image, the light socket is "standard" and the intermediate section contains a three prong outlet. Of course, this portion would remain hot when the camera is live, but it would also be accepting of the remote outlet switching device previously described.

One would leave the wall switch in the on position and use the app or physical button on the switching device to manage illumination of the accent lights. An additional feature of the switching device is the ability to program a schedule for on/off times, removing the "manual" aspect and placing the system into an automatic mode if desired.

Comment: What, exactly, is this "Y-adapter", where does it screw in, and how does it get constant power? I'm envisioning a dual-bulb adapter that screws into the socket where the camera is currently located and cannot fathom how this will magically make the power constantly hot. I'm guessing I don't understand what you're suggesting. Please clarify.

Comment: OK, that _is_ what I thought you were referring to. However, I still don't see how this will work... Keeping the switch on 24/7 will provide power to the camera, but, AIUI, the rest of the accent lights are _also_ hardwired sockets on this same switch-controlled circuit branch, so they'd have power all the time, too. I don't see how a smart outlet installed somewhere in the middle of a string of fixtures will allow control over all but one of the fixtures. I'm sure I'm still just missing something...

Comment: Take the phone-controlled block from the first image and plug it into the outlet in the third image. Plug the accent lights into the block. With the wall switch on powering the camera in the bulb outlet, power also goes to the phone-controlled block. The accent lights can be switched off and on as desired using the block.

Comment: I think we have different understanding of the question. You're envisioning plug in lights, and I'm envisioning 20 hard-wired fixtures. Not sure which of us is right, hence my request on the OP for more info...

Comment: I neglected to notice that Larry is the OP and FreeMan is just making comments. The reference to a light bulb socket adapter eliminates the hard-wired aspect of this question. It's easy to understand that a camera would have a bulb-type screw in power source, as I have one. The accent lights are less likely to be so equipped and are more likely to be ordinary plug power sourced. Larry does need to chime in here.

Comment: -1 Can't have an answer recommending **DANGEROUS STUFF**. That light bulb adapter is a disaster waiting to happen. Why? It has a 3-prong receptacle. That means hot, neutral, ground. But an Edison light bulb socket, *by definition*, only has hot and neutral. Which means ground is faked (bad) or bonded to neutral (worse!). Don't recommend stuff that isn't at least *possible* to be UL/ETL/etc. listed.

Comment: I neglected to note that the adapter "converts" a two wire circuit to a three wire circuit. I'm sure those accent lights require a standard ground as well as a hot and neutral.